# Finding the weighted sum of a tree

Tags: prolog

I'm working on a small prolog program to work a bit with binary trees and am trying to find the weighted sum of the tree. Each of the nodes has a value and this is then to be multiplied by the depth of the node. I was trying to use an accumulator here and I keep getting the error that the arguments are not sufficiently instantiated.

I've started with using the implementation found here: http://people.sju.edu/~jhodgson/ai/accums.html

And it seems to be a fairly standard thing.

I've attempted to leave off various parts of my predicate just to see where the problem is and the problem appears when I include S1 and S2 in my sum calculation.

```
tree_wsum(Tree, S) :- tree_wsum(Tree, S, 0).

tree_wsum(nil, Sum, Depth).
tree_wsum(tree(Root, Left, Right), Sum, Depth) :- D1 is Depth + 1, tree_wsum(Left, S1, D1), tree_wsum(Right, S2, D1), Sum is (Depth * Root) + S1 + S2.
```

D1 and the Depth * Root calculation are fine, but adding S1 and/or S2 throws the following error:

ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [12] _6020 is 2*1+_6028
ERROR:   [11] tree_wsum(tree(1,nil,nil),_6060,2) at :28

Comment: ```tree_wsum(nil, Sum, Depth).``` this is Your base case thus Sum should have a value ?

Answer (score -1):

```
tree_wsum(Tree, Sum) :- 
    tree_wsum(Tree, Sum, 0).
tree_wsum(nil,0,_).
tree_wsum(tree(X,Left,Right), Sum, Depth) :-
    D1 is Depth+1,
    tree_wsum(Left, S1,D1), 
    tree_wsum(Right, S2,D1),
    Sum is (X*D1)+S1+S2.
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation, it might not be clear to everyone.